# Ternary Operator Equivalent in Java Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to compare the end results of a series operations on two variables. Since operations are the same, I use java stream on these two variables. But I need to return the results based on the sub-variables of the objects. For example:

```java
class MyClass {
  String strVal;
  Integer intVal;
}

MyClass myFunction(MyClass myClass1, MyClass myClass2) {
   Stream.of(myClass1, myClass2)
      .map(function) // get intVal for both objects
      .filter(predicate)
      ...
   // return myClass1 if myClass1.intVal > myClass2.intVal, otherwise myClass2
   // current implementation
   return myClass1.intVal > myClass2.intVal ? myClass1 : myClass2;

}
```

Are there ternary operator equivalent that can be used in stream? Maybe need to create new Functional Interfaces?

The reason why I'm asking is that this is not the only place in the code to get the value based on the comparison results. Some places I need to use a function like

```
return myClass1.intVal > myClass2.intVal ? function(myClass1) : function(myClass2);
```

I understand how stream is implemented, like the comment section mentioned below. But the whole concept is to make the code cleaner. So if there's a cleaner way to return the value with only one function, it's better than repeating the function for all variables.

Comment: If you're filtering, what should you return if the predicate is false for one or both values? What are `function` and `predicate`? Please see [mcve].

Comment: @kaya3, I'll throw an exception. `function` is a transform to get all the values for the objects. `predicate` is to check if certain fields of the transformed results are expected.

Comment: What do you think `Stream.of(myClass1, myClass2)` does? It iterates over `myClass1` _and then_ `myClass2`.  Nowhere do you have access to both objects at the same time.  It's not clear what you're asking.  Your existing implementation is fine.

Comment: What if they're equal?

Comment: Is it always just two elements?  If so, I think using streams is overkill here.  If not, then I smell an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) and you should provide more concrete examples of what you're trying to accomplish.  Streams seem to be the 21st century version of regular expressions.  A cool-looking shiny new tool that gets misapplied because it's cool.

Comment: @JimGarrison the ternary operator would take care of the equal scenarios right?
It is always just two elements. The problem is that there are a lot of steps in between, there would be lots of duplicate code not using streams.

Comment: Not unless you nested ternary operators. You have 3 conditions for which an output must be specified, `<`, `=` and `>`.

Comment: If you don't want to repeat the `function(...)` call, why not just write `return function(... ? myClass1 : myClass2);`? Or you could assign the ternary result to a variable and then `return function(result);`.

Comment: @kaya3 there's a function takes in both of the variables, left argument is the larger one, right is the smaller one.

Comment: @Sophia then, you should describe exactly that in your question, instead of describing something entirely different.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing just 2 elements I stick to ternary operator, but if you really want to use streams, then you could do it by using the `.max()` method passing it a comparator in which you define which object is greater based on your policy (in this case who has the bigger intVal), like this:

```java
MyClass myFunction(MyClass myClass1, MyClass myClass2) {
    // return myClass1 if myClass1.intVal > myClass2.intVal, otherwise myClass2
    return Stream.of(myClass1, myClass2)
            .max((m1, m2) -> m1.intVal.compareTo(m2.intVal))
            .get();
}
```

Comment: Do you find this answer to be significantly different than the previous answer?

Comment: @matt Yes, because it provides an explanation.

Answer (score -1):

```
  public static MyClass myFunction(MyClass myClass1, MyClass myClass2) {
    List<MyClass> list = List.of(myClass1,myClass2);
    return list.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(MyClass::getIntVal))
                        .orElseThrow(NoSuchElementException::new);
}
```

Comment: So I don't want to return the maximum int value, I want to return the object with the max intVal.

Comment: There’s no need to create a `List` just to call `stream()`. Use `Stream.of(myClass1, myClass2)` in the first place. Then, it’s preferable to use `Comparator.comparingInt` when you know that the property has an `int` type. Won’t matter much in this case but it’s a good habit. Unless you’re stuck with Java 8, you can simply use `orElseThrow()`, without an explicit `NoSuchElementException::new`.

Comment: @Sophia this answer’s code does return the object.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.